# Is there a way to swap corpus dependant on detected language in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I've got the below script which will detect a language based upon amount of stop words. Which will then invoke another script for tagging. However, I can't seem to figure out how to swap the corpus being loaded (currently its browns):

`tagger = UnigramTagger(nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents())`, depending on the detected language. Is there a method I can call? Or is it a case of switching on input on initial setup, or have multiple processes that are setup for each language?

#!/usr/bin/env python
    #coding:utf_8

```
"""
Imports
"""
import sys
import getopt
import socket
import select
import pprint
import json
import subprocess

try:
    from nltk import wordpunct_tokenize
    from nltk.tag import UnigramTagger
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
except ImportError:
    print '[!] Missing NLTK packages. Attempting to install. This may take a while!'
    subprocess.call('python scripts/SetupNltk.py', shell=True)

"""
Globals
"""

"""
Definitions
"""
def _calculate_languages_ratio(text):
    languages_ratios = {}
    tokens = wordpunct_tokenize(text)
    words = [word.lower() for word in tokens]
    for language in stopwords.fileids():
        stopwords_set = set(stopwords.words(language))
        words_set = set(words)
        common_elements = words_set.intersection(stopwords_set)
        languages_ratios[language] = len(common_elements)

    return languages_ratios


def detect_language(text):
    ratios = _calculate_languages_ratio(text)
    return max(ratios, key=ratios.get)


"""
Main entry point
"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    language = detect_language(text)
    print language
```

Comment: According to the documentation for each corpus there is a class and instance object which is used to read it.  So once you have identified the corpus you want to use, import its corpus reader object and reference it to access its contents as shown at http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html#overview.

Comment: Well that's the point of the question really, I don't know how to import the correct corpus once I've detected the language, I was wondering if there was a method that automatically loaded the correct corpus, if I passed in a language.

Comment: I think you mean the question is how to determine the best corpus for your needs depending on the language, because if you know what corpus to use, importing is trivial. Perhaps you have some sample data that needs classifying. A test set with known classification metrics would be great. Then you can use it to evaluate several corpora selected by educated guess or curiosity to determine which actually gives the best results compared to the benchmark.  I do not know of a tool that does this automatically.